# How to avoid Mail.app grouping mails

Tags: mail.app

While i generally like the newest Mail.app, i particularly dislike that it groups all messages that i receive from a specific sender. This makes it difficult to remove a specific message and i would like to disable it.

Is there a way to turn grouping off and show messages in single message mode, like the older Mail.app was doing ?

Answer (score 4):

Toggle the `View > Organize by Conversation` menu item.

Comment: Good answer.  And if you subscribe to RSS feeds, you'll have to do this for each feed.